# Reading from csv to pandas, chardet and error bad lines options do not work in my case

Tags: python, csv, pandas, unicode

I checked similar questions before I write here, also I tried to use try/except... where try does nothing, except prints bad line but couldn't solve my issue. So currently I have:

```
import pandas as pd
import chardet

# Read the file
with open("full_data.csv", 'rb') as f:
    result = chardet.detect(f.read())  # or readline if the file is large

df1 = pd.read_csv("full_data.csv", sep=';',
                   encoding=result['encoding'], error_bad_lines=False, low_memory=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

But I still get the error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xba in position 9: invalid start byte
```

Is there any option similar to error = 'replace' in open csv ? Or any other solutions

Comment: Well, first you are reading the file in binary mode to determine encoding, but then you are feeding it to df as plain text. Could you post few lines of your csv, or at least determine content?

Comment: I think there are some Russian, Latin and Chinese characters, I don't mind to replace them with '?' or anything else

Comment: Okay, but first, why are you using binary reading mode to determine encoding?

Comment: When I read as plain text also I get, :
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9e in position 3785643: character maps to <undefined>

Answer (score 1):

Using engine option sovles my problem:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("full_data.csv", sep=";", engine="python")
```